# Angular Tree component not working

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-tree-component

I installed and imported angular tree component and tried setting it up using the basic example provided following the steps in https://angular2-tree.readme.io/

But unfortunately I only see the root node and without expand. Posting the code can someone just see off the bat if anything is wrong? Please help me understand the error I oviously am not able to see.

Module:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { TreeModule } from 'angular-tree-component';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    TreeModule
  ],
  declarations: [],
  providers: []
})
export class CourseCreationModule { }
```

Component:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router, ActivatedRoute, Params } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-container',
  templateUrl: './container.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./container.component.css']
})
export class ContainerComponent implements OnInit {
  tree: any;

  constructor() { }

  getCourseDetails() {
      this.createLessonTree();
  }

  createLessonTree() {
    this.tree = [
      {
        id: 1,
        name: 'root1',
        children: [
          { 
            id: 2, 
            name: 'child1'
          },
          { id: 3, 
            name: 'child2'
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        id: 4,
        name: 'root2',
        children: [
          { id: 5, name: 'child2.1' },
          {
            id: 6,
            name: 'child2.2',
            children: [
              { id: 7, name: 'subsub' }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ];
  }

ngOnInit() {
this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
  this.courseId = params['id'];
  this.getCourseDetails();
});
}
```

HTML:

```
<tree-root [nodes]="tree"></tree-root>
```

Believe there are no sytax errors as I can see `root1` and `root2`.

Thank you.

Comment: Where are you calling `getCourseDetails()`?

Comment: I found a solution to this issue in this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47642137/angular-2-tree-only-shows-root-nodes?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Answer (score 6):

Added `@import '~angular-tree-component/dist/angular-tree-component.css';` to the `src/styles.css` file and worked.

Comment: or you can add this to your angular.json styles property "styles": ["./node_modules/angular-tree-component/dist/angular-tree-component.css","src/styles.css"]

Answer (score 1):

I believe you need to call `getCourseDetails()` in your constructor or in `ngOnInit()` which should be implemented as the class declaration states.

Comment: That is not required the function gets invoked. As I had said syntax might not be a problem as the tree component is being called and I can see the root nodes being displayed. The problem is the children are not being appended.

Comment: Why would you see it if you do not invoke the constructing function?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion have invoked the code from ngOnInit which I havn't added in the code.

Comment: any solution for this issue! I am facing same

Comment: @NIrav Modi, check out the solution on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47642137/angular-2-tree-only-shows-root-nodes?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

I had to include `@import '~angular-tree-component/dist/angular-tree-component.css'; ` to my src/styles.css file to get it to work.

Comment: I can not see even root nodes. Do you think this will resolve?

Answer (score 0):

If this issue occurs after migrating to `@circlon/angular-tree-component`, you should use `@import '~@circlon/angular-tree-component/css/angular-tree-component.css'` in your `src/styles.css`.
See also: [changelog](https://github.com/CirclonGroup/angular-tree-component/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#901-2020-07-15)