# Angular 2 tree only shows root nodes

Tags: angular, tree

The angular2-tree library has a straightforward [*Basic Usage* example](https://angular2-tree.readme.io/docs#basic-usage).  However, when I put it into my project, only the root nodes are rendered.  In other words, the tree should have parents (rootA, rootB) and children,

```
export class App {
  nodes = [
    {
      id: 1,
      name: 'rootA',
      children: [
        { id: 2, name: 'child1' },
        { id: 3, name: 'child2' }
      ]
    },
    {
      id: 4,
      name: 'rootB',
      children: [
        { id: 5, name: 'child2.1' },
        {
          id: 6,
          name: 'child2.2',
          children: [
            { id: 7, name: 'subsub' }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ];
```

But all I see are root nodes.

There are no compilation issues, and I've included the css import:

```
@import '~angular-tree-component/dist/angular-tree-component.css';
```

Has anyone had a similar issue?

[image]

Stack is Angular 4, Chrome, Windows 10.

Answer (score 2):

You need to copy the css content from `node_modules\angular-tree-component\distangular-tree-component.css` and paste the contents on `styles.css` file present under `src` folder of your application.

Or alternatively you can also add this statement in the `styles.css` file.

```
@import '~angular-tree-component/dist/angular-tree-component.css';
```

This will solve the problem.